Does OutOfMemoryException in async web request crush other currently running async web requests
I am intending to use async methods in ASP.NET Core MVC. I know they run on event loop.
If inside a particular async method (web request) an out of memory error occurs, does it crush other currently running async methods?
If that happens to be true, that would it mean to web page visitors associated with those currently running async methods - would they get an error?

Does this answer your question? 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown when there is still plenty of memory free

I am asking this because async architecture uses single thread.

If you want to know what happens test it and find out.  Perform a bunch of requests, deliberately use up all of the memory, and see what happens.

"I am asking this because async architecture uses single thread."  This is not true.  An ASP application is going to have lots of threads.  That each request doesn't have their own dedicated thread for the duration of the request doesn't mean that the whole application only has a single thread for its whole existence.

.net core handle multiple tasks concurrently without blocking threads.They do not run on an event loop but instead use the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern and the .NET thread pool to manage concurrency. If an out of memory  error occurs within an async method, it does not directly impact other running async methods. Each web request in ASP.NET Core is handled independently, and errors within one request do not necessarily affect other requests.

No.
One Out-of-Memory exception does not imply anything about the general health of the application.
From here:

In short, and very simplified, "Out of memory" does not really mean that the amount of available memory is too small. The most common reason is that within the current address space, there is no contiguous portion of memory that is large enough to serve the wanted allocation. If you have 100 blocks, each 4 MB large, that is not going to help you when you need one 5 MB block.

Also:

ASP.NET Core is not single-threaded.
Based on the limited information you've provided, an "event loop" is not necessarily in play for your scenario.

